# In Excel, looking for a way to convert MATCH formula into a wildcard match to find if a list of terms exist in multiple phrases

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, vlookup

I'm looking for a way to convert a Match formula that I use to routinely to check for matches into a wildcard match for Match. I know there is an MatchType parameter in the MATCH formula but when changing from 0 to 1 it does not produce the desired wildcard match I'm looking for.

For exact matches the formula I use is

`=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A2,'Lookup wildcard phrase'!A$2:A$4,0)),"FALSE","TRUE")`

1. In the first tab, I have this data

[image]

2. In the second tab, I have this data

[image]

For my needs with Exact Matches, I can use this formula

`=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A2,'Lookup wildcard phrase'!A$2:A$4,0)),"FALSE","TRUE")` to populate the second column row by row in the first tab.

[image]

How would I modify this to compare a wildcard for any term column A for every row from first tab with the Match range for column A in the second tab?

I tried experimenting with what I believe is a wildcard with VLOOKUP formula as well but it did not work either.

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP("*"&A2&"*",'Lookup wildcard phrase'!A$2:A$4,1,FALSE)),"FALSE","TRUE")
```

Comment: What is your desired result for given sample? Is phrase "magpie" positive for term "pie" ? is phrase "somebody's" positive for term "somebody"?

Comment: `=OR(ISNUMBER(MATCH("*"&'Lookup wildcard phrase'!A$2:A$4&"*",A2,0)))`

Comment: Or `=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(SEARCH('Lookup wildcard phrase'!A$2:A$4,A2),0))>0`

Comment: @ScottCraner got very similar solution to your second. SUM instead of SUMPRODUCT would be enough!

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya that depends on the OP answering the first comment question.  This works as long as the phrase "magpie" is a positive for term "pie".  So I will wait for the answer to that question before posting.

Comment: Looking at the Screen shots, it looks like in Column B the OP wants a List of words from the Wildcard list, but I may be over analyzing it

Comment: @user11222393 SUM works in Office 365 but not older versions. At least without the need for Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: @user11222393 it is for whole words in each of the phrases like "pie" or "somebody" or "fall". I tried both formulas and they both successfully evaluate as needed for "pie" but as well for magpie and magpies which would be false positive.  Would there be a way to make it ignore such words only partially containing the wildcard word or wildcard phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to OP's comment that "magpie" is negative for "pie", this should work:

```
=SUM(N(TEXTSPLIT(A2," ")=$A$11:$A$13))>0
```

[image]

Or to spill at once:

```
=BYROW(A2:A6,LAMBDA(x,SUM(N(TEXTSPLIT(x," ")=$A$11:$A$13))>0))
```

Comment: The lookup wildcards list are on a different tab not in the same tab. Can you please provide a working formula utilizing the lookup referenced 'Lookup wildcard phrase'!A$2:A$4

Comment: Put it in B1 cell in phrases tab: =SUM(N(TEXTSPLIT(A1," ")='Lookup wildcard phrase'!$A$2:$A$4))>0  , take a note that absolute reference $A$2:$A$4 and not A$2:A$4 is used